# Why do Grignard reagents add to propargyl alcohols?

Tags: organic-chemistry, alcohols, regioselectivity, stereoselectivity, grignard-reagent

In Phil Baran's [lectures on heterocyclic chemistry at Scripps](https://itunes.apple.com/us/course/heterocyclic-chemistry-2015/id981272539), one of the lecture problems is concerned with this synthesis of Vioxx:

[image: Vioxx synthesis]

The first step supposedly involves an *anti* addition of the aryl Grignard reagent to the propargyl alcohol:

[image: Grignard addition to propargyl alcohol]

and this intermediate is trapped with $\ce{CO2}$ to form a lactone (a butenolide in this case), and *m*CPBA oxidises the sulfide to a sulfone.

Why does the aryl Grignard add to the alkyne in this case? I would expect it to deprotonate the alcohol, and it does seem to do so, but as far as I know, Grignards don't usually add to alkynes which aren't conjugated to electron-withdrawing groups. Why is this propargyl alcohol special?

On top of that, what is the rationale for the selectivity observed (both regio- and stereoselectivity)?

Comment: It looks wrong. It doesn't seem to be made this way https://books.google.pl/books?id=fsKKI82uqK8C&pg=PA13&lpg=PA13&dq=rofecoxib+synthesis&source=bl&ots=IQ2sW9FSkU&sig=-Vg6ESf3XVuis2m5piHCpGSMixw&hl=pl&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwjCvNaI0KvRAhWC2SwKHcL9AtcQ6AEIMTAG#v=onepage&q=rofecoxib%20synthesis&f=false

Comment: @Mithoron I think that this wasn't the one that Merck opted to go for. However, this alternative synthesis was reported in [*Tetrahedron Lett.* **2000,** *41* (1), 17–20](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0040403999019954) (apparently, there is a non-paywall version [here](http://mysite.science.uottawa.ca/afallis/furans.PDF) as well).

Comment: Then the reaction is rather with salt after neutralisation of alcohol.

Comment: @orthocresol looks like reference 1 in that paper is the original report of that reaction. Check if they postulated a mechanism?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The addition of Grignards to propargyl alcohols occurs via the alkoxide salt, after deprotonation:<sup>[1]</sup>

[image: Reaction scheme]

Here:

- the *reactivity* may be explained by the stabilising influence of complexation;
- the *regioselectivity* may be explained by the preference of a five-membered chelate ring over a four-membered one; and
- the *stereoselectivity* arises because *syn* addition requires a five-membered ring with a *trans* double bond and is therefore precluded.

In fact, propargylic alcohols also get reduced by $\ce{LiAlH4}$ ([Hans Reich's website has a page on it](http://www.chem.wisc.edu/areas/reich/chem547/2-redox%7B05%7D.htm)), with the same *trans* stereochemistry observed.

---

**Reference**

(1) Forgione, P.; Fallis, A. G. Magnesium mediated carbometallation of propargyl alcohols: direct routes to dihydroxydienes and enediyne alcohols. *Tetrahedron Lett.* **2000,** *41* (1), 11–15. [DOI: 10.1016/S0040-4039(99)01994-2](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0040-4039(99)01994-2).

Comment: Note that the oxygen can withdraw electron drnsity from the methylebe grouo, giving it some catbovation character; this polarized carbon is then conjugated with the end of the triple bond where the nucleophilic part of the Grignard reagent attacks.